# Datatables.net: Export to Excel with header image

Tags: jquery, excel, image, datatables

I'm using Datatables.net buttons plugin (excelHtml5) to preview and export data in Excel format. I would like to know how to add an image to the Excel document header (first rows).

How can i accomplish this?